# Hibernate WHERE does not work for @Embedded with null member

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class `Posting` with an `@Embedded`:

```
public class Posting {
  @Embedded
  private BankDetails bankDetails;      
}

public class BankDetails {
    private String bankCode;
    private String bankName;
}
```

Now I want to list all `Posting`s with a `bankCode` of `123` and a `bankName` of `null`.

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT o from Posting o WHERE bankDetails=?");
q.setParameter(1, new BankDetails("123", null));
```

However I don't get any results.

Why?

Here's the sql query Hibernate executes:

```
select posting0_.bank_code as bank_cod6_42_, posting0_.bank_name as bank_nam7_42_
from posting posting0_ 
where (posting0_.bank_code, posting0_.bank_name)=('123', null)
```

(Btw, this parentheses syntax is called *Row Value Constructors*.)

That obviously does not work because is compares `null` with `=`.

1. Is this a bug? If yes, which component generates the SQL statement? (Hibernate? the mysql-connector?)
2. Any ideas for a workaround?

*Environment: MySQL Server 5.7 on Win10, Spring 4.0.3, Hibernate 4.3.11, mysql-connector 5.1.30*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **bug** in Hibernate 4 and 5.

It should be fixed in Hibernate 6: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8172

See @Naros answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a workaround, but it requires you to be a bit more verbose with the query.

```
entityManager.createQuery( "SELECT o FROM Posting o WHERE " +
    " o.bankDetails.bankCode = ? " +
    " AND o.bankDetails.bankName IS NULL" );
entityManager.setParameter( 1, "123" );
```

I honestly haven't seen a query generated with a tuple value like that, but most of my past experience has been with SQL Server that does not support such a syntax.  If you believe it's a bug, please feel free to open a [JIRA](http://hibernate.atlassian.net) issue.

Comment: In SQL Server the syntax would probably be `where (posting0_.bank_code, posting0_.bank_name) IN ('123', null)`but i cannot verify that.

Comment: I can't comment on MSSQL2012+ but I do know that MSSQL2008 and prior, that syntax is **not** valid.